# how to view the design of xaml file in xamarin forms pcl in visula studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Now i am going on with the development of xamarin forms pcl project,i have created a xaml file in my portable lib there i can't view the design.

Tried to fix it by the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921077.aspx

http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/

How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are no designer support from Xamarin, as it would be bit of complicated, but you might find Xamarin Forms Player a good tool to go,

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ed9794a-2021-486a-9bca-4851c7ee7316

Comment: actually i am new to visual studio can you please guide any link by step by step

Comment: any toolbar will be there for this to drag and drop the ui like as in android and ios

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's XAML Designer currently does not support Xamarin XAML files.There's no designer for it atm.

Even though their syntax are very similiar , there are some slight differences between them.

Comment: is there any other go

Comment: because i need to develop it by portable with xaml file

Comment: any other file to use in portable or plugin

Comment: Nothing unfortunately afaik.

If you want to get Intellisense feature in Xamarin XAML files , you might use ReSharper or simply just use Xamarin Studio for your XAML files.But there's no designer like feature in Xamarin for XAML files atm.

Comment: The syntax is not the problem, but Xamarin.Forms is converted to platform dependent native controls at runtime, so even harder to provide previews at design time.