# About XAML.Forms Previewer in VS2015

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

In VS2015 U3 if I try to use `XAM.Forms` Previewer the interface is empty and have only  the "Android Phone" message without my XAML user interface.

[image]

I tried to rebuild the solution but the preview still doesn't works!

Whats happened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to view the design of xaml file in xamarin forms pcl in visula studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596716/how-to-view-the-design-of-xaml-file-in-xamarin-forms-pcl-in-visula-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, **XAML Previewer** still has alot of issues with **Visual Studio 2015**. I'm encountering the same problem and I just followed the steps from an official [Xamarin blogpost.](https://blog.xamarin.com/live-xaml-previewing-with-the-xamarin-forms-previewer/) There are workarounds shared by other developers, but it didn't work for me. [See link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70095/xaml-previewer-for-xamarin-forms-not-show-in-visual-studio).

But, I'd suggest you try out [Gorilla Player](http://gorillaplayer.com/). It's an instant **Xamarin Forms XAML Previewer**. You can also **simultaneously view the design without compiling**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, i now installing Gorilla Player!